# Select statement in Select statement is this correct way

Tags: sql

What is wrong in this `statement` is there a way to improve it?

```
SELECT i.head, i.subhead, c.category
from items i,
     category c 
WHERE c.category = i.category
AND (i.subhead IN (SELECT i.head
                   FROM items i,
                        category c
                   WHERE c.category = i.category) or i.subhead = 0)
```

What I would like to get is that a `subhead` should be in `head` so that I can check if this  `subhead` has a `parent` without that do not display it and if `subhead` is `0` that means it has no parents so display it. Is it okay or should it be replaced with an `join` or something like this? I have result set from the `SELECT` so I am adding an `AND` with the same result of table where I check for my condition.

Comment: Syntax error, remove `,` before `or`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use CTE feature (Common Table Expression) if your DBMS supports it.

```
WITH rawData AS (
  SELECT i.head
  FROM items i
  JOIN category c ON (c.category = i.category)
)
SELECT i.head, i.subhead, c.category
FROM items i
JOIN category c ON (c.category = i.category)
WHERE (i.subhead IN (SELECT head FROM rawData) OR i.subhead = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT i.head, i.subhead, c.category
from items i join category c 
on c.category = i.category
where i.subhead IN (SELECT i.head
                    FROM items i join category c on c.category = i.category)
 or i.subhead = 0
```